# Updated MS Access table by joining other table not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update an MS Access table by joining it to another table in another database and it's not working.

Here is the code I used:

```
UPDATE   tbl_a  a
INNER JOIN tbl_a  b 
  IN '' [MS Access;PWD=Cb4XTNLq34c$;DATABASE=C:\data\memberdetails.mdb]  
  ON a.mobile=b.mobile
SET a.Mobilenew = b.Mobilenew, 
    a.isUpdated = 1, 
    a.Operator = b.Operator 
WHERE b.isupdated=1
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is not the way to post a question. First, format it properly; second, tag it properly; third, explain why it is not working (error message, result, etc.); fourth, present sample data (of the tables being accessed by the command); fifth, present the table definition; sixth, show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is join the table to the database you're using.  To do that, you should:

1. Click on "External Data" menu item on the top of Access
2. Click the Access icon
3. You're given a choice of importing or linking data.  Choose "Link"
4. Browse and select the database containing the data you want to link (in your case, C:\data\memberdetails.mdb
5. You will be presented with a list of tables in the database.  Choose which table(s) you want, and click OK

The new table will now exist in your database as a *linked* table.  At that point, you can change your query to:

```
UPDATE   tbl_a  a
INNER JOIN tbl_a  b 
  ON a.mobile=b.mobile
SET a.Mobilenew = b.Mobilenew, 
    a.isUpdated = 1, 
    a.Operator = b.Operator 
WHERE b.isupdated=1
```

Since they're linked, any change that's made to tbl_a in either database will effect both databases, so just keep that in mind which you're working with it.